# TortoiseGit skipping rebase (wrong preference)

Tags: tortoisegit, preference

After latest update of **TortoiseGit**, there is added preference to **automatically skip rebasing/fast-forwarding** when there is nothing to rebase. I accidentally chose this option in dialog but TortoiseGit enabled it permanently and I can't change it back.

Do you know of any way how to **reset this preference**?
Do you know how to reset all TortoiseGit preferences or where they are stored? (Uninstall didn't help.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I think I have discovered where the settings are saved.
You should open regedit and go to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGit
```

There you will find a DWORD setting:

```
OpenRebaseRemoteBranchUnchanged
```

And there is also a similar one which mentiones fast forward. You can delete both of them and the prompt window will reappear again.